# How to Replace Specific value with other value in django database column?

Tags: django

I have a Table "Subscriber" in which one column whose name is Status.

I want to replace value of "status" column.Where status = 1 and 3 change it with 4. In other words all '1 and 3' status convert into 4.

What should i do to solve this problem.

Comment: *Try*, its something thats covered in lots of detail already in the documentation, with plenty of helpful links already available on your favourite search engine. [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@e4c5's solution is perfectly good, though I try to reserve `Q` objects for complex queries, in this case, I might just go with the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in) filter: `Subscriber.objects.filter(status__in=[1, 3]).update(status=4)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to get the `OR` condition. The rest of it is a simple call to update

```
Subscriber.objects.filter(Q(status=1)|Q(status=3)).update(status=4)
```

> Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together.
>   If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with
>   OR statements), you can use Q objects.

Read the documentation for update here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: #e4c5 It would also hit directly database or should i save it before

Comment: A = Subscriber.objects.filter(Q(status=1)|Q(status=3)).update(status=4)  A.save should do this step or not ?

Comment: Migration is required or not ?

Comment: Why do you need migrations to run an update?? I strongly recommend that you read the django queryset documentation page

Comment: I suspect this is what the op was actually trying to do, although they mention "and" in their question which may mean status can hold multiple different values at once

Comment: Good point @sayse. Learnt my lesson  to keep away from these unclear questions.